# Java Generics syntax setter

Tags: java, generics

I have this two classes and i need to initialize in the child class filds from parent class.

```
public class A {

    protected LazyFacade<E> list;
    protected LazyDataModel<E> model;
    protected MyObject myObject;

    protected LazyDataModel<E> buildModel() {
            lazyModel = new LazyDataModel<E>() {
                public List<E> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
                    List<E> resultList = null;
                    try {
                        setRowCount((int) list.countObjects(myObject, filters));
                        resultList = list.listObject(myObject, first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, filters);
                    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
                    }
                    return resultList;
                }
            };
        return lazyModel;
    }
    //getters setters
}

public class B extends A {

    public B() {
        this.list = new LazyFacade<OtherClass>();   **//is it correct way to instantiate the list???**
        this.myObject = getObjectInDataBase();
        this.model = buildModel();                  **//the model must have the same class of LazyFacade, in this case OtherClass.
                                                    //How could i do it?**
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? And what do you think `E` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `public class A {` to `public class A<E> {`

Comment: OK Daniel, but i dont want to create inside class B  a new A<OtherClass>.
What i need is initialize the fields in subclass, because only in subclass i will know the parameter E type.

The this.list = new LazyFacade<OtherClass>(); works appearly. But how could i set the E parameter for model field in subclass?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i'm not understanding the question, but i think you need to include that generic on the class declaration line or you'll get an error. Also, to instantiate the superclass's fields you might want to change `this.model = buildModel();` to `this.model = super.buildModel();`

Comment: Try changing the B class to
`public class B<E> extends A<E> {

    public B() {
        this.list = new LazyFacade<E>();
        this.myObject = getObjectInDataBase();
        this.model = buildModel();
    }
}`

then instantiate a B object with:
`B<OtherClass> test = new B<>();`